# Can I say "He recommended you much"

Tags: expressions

I need to mark that someone made some effort to recommend third person services and it was something more than "he is good in that".

Checking [a dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/much), *much* is an adverb meaning "to a great extent; a great deal"

Is the phrase "He the recommended you much" suitable for showing such praise? Is there a better way? If there is, why?

Comment: We would normally say *He recommended you highly*.

Comment: Added a little research. *Much* **is** an adverb. Perhaps there is something unusual about the verb *recommend*.

Comment: I have heard something like "He recommended you muchly" ... but only as a joke.

Comment: _Much_ can be an adverb, but is little used in a positive sense in the UK (I think it is used a bit more in the US). However _very much_ is widely used as an adverbial expression in the UK, both positive and negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

*Much* is used more in negative than in affirmative contexts. *A lot* has no such restriction, and that's one reason why it's so common.

- *I've never liked it a lot.*
- *I've never liked it much.*
- *I've always liked it a lot.*
- **I've always liked it much.*

Another reason *a lot* is common is because it doesn't distinguish mass from count nouns; there's a similar pattern for *many*, with plural count nouns.

- *I never eat a lot of them at once.*
- *I never eat many of them at once.*
- *I always eat a lot of them at once.*
- **I always eat many of them at once.*

*Much* and *many* are on the [NPI list](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf), but they're not **quite** NPIs; there are a lot of affirmative environments where they can appear grammatically. Of course, as quantifiers, they already participate in a slew of idioms and odd constructions, so that's not really news.